# Firebase App Check / App Attest Internal Error -iOS

Tags: ios, swift, app-store-connect, firebase-app-check

When using Xcode, and running my app, I'm able to access Firebase via App Check / App Attest doing the following:

```
let providerFactory = AppCheckDebugProviderFactory()
AppCheck.setAppCheckProviderFactory(providerFactory)
```

Once I get the `Firebase App Check debug token`. I manually add the token to Firebase `Console` > `App Check`

**But when I uploaded my app to App Review, they can't login, they get an error code of**

> 17999 - Internal Error

**Why is it  Firebase via App Check / App Attest, Firebase isn't accessible in production/going live?**

I took the following steps:

I updated to the most `recent pods`.

In **Firebase Console**:

`App Check` > `Apps` > `AppAttest` > Registered and added my Team ID. Token time to live set to 1 hour (default) > `Save`

In **AppDelegate**:

```
import FirebaseAppCheck

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    override init() {
        super.init()
        
        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
        
        let providerFactory = YourAppCheckProviderFactory()
        AppCheck.setAppCheckProviderFactory(providerFactory)
        
        FirebaseApp.configure()
    }
}

class YourAppCheckProviderFactory: NSObject, AppCheckProviderFactory {
  func createProvider(with app: FirebaseApp) -> AppCheckProvider? {
    return AppAttestProvider(app: app)
  }
}
```

In **Xcode**:

`Edit Schemes` > `Run` > `Arguments` > `FIRDebugEnabled` is checked

Downloaded the most recent *Google-Info.plist* from `Firebase Console` > `Project Overview` > `Project Settings` > `General` > `Apple apps` > Replaced the previous one in my project with the most recent one

`Targets` > `Signing & Capabilities` > added `App Attest`

In the `Entitlements File` > `App Attest Environment : production`

In **Google Cloud Console**:

`Credentials` > `Key Restrictions : None` > `API restrictions : Don't restrict keys`

`APIs & Services` > `Library` > `Token Service API`: `enabled`

In **developer.apple.com**:

`Certificates, IDs & Profiles` > `Certificates` > `Keys` > created a `Device Check key`

**Images** (for other people who may come across this issue):

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem occurred because my Firebase pods were outdated. They were on **8.15.0** when they should've been on the current version which is **10.17.0**.

To check you pod version go to your app's main folder, open terminal, cd to it, and run `open -a TextEdit Podfile.lock` or `vim Podfile.lock` and check your firebase pod version. To update run `pod outdated` then `pod update`

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to add the signing and capabilities "App Attest" and ensure the identifier is made for App Attest on the Developer Account.

Comment: You might want to elaborate, desribe the effect of what you propose and explain why it helps to solve the problem.